# How do I create a folder in the home directory on raspberry pi?

Tags: linux, passwords, admin, raspberry-pi, root

I need to know how its done. Do I need to be a superuser/ admin user?
Do I need a root password
I only have one user onthe pi if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use sudo to run mkdir on the root folder on any linux version:

```
sudo mkdir somedir
```

Enter the root password when sudo prompts for it.

Comment: home directory is not root so no need for sudo.